# Get the first value from Oracle cursor - Calling From Java Code

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, stored-functions

I have a oracle cursor which I have created to facilitate concurrency. This is my cursor.

```
create or replace FUNCTION get_unlocked_records RETURN table_to_test%ROWTYPE IS
CURSOR c IS SELECT * FROM table_to_test where status_code = 5 FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED;
record_to_get table_to_test%ROWTYPE;
    BEGIN
        OPEN c;
        FETCH c INTO record_to_get;
        CLOSE c;
        RETURN record_to_get;
    END;
```

When I do the testing in 2 separate sql sessions using these commands,it gives the following errors.

```
declare
  record_to_gets table_to_test%ROWTYPE;    
begin
 exec :record_to_gets := get_unlocked_records;
 dbms_output.put_line(record_to_gets);
end;
```

Error

```
Error starting at line : 32 in command -
declare
  record_to_gets   table_to_test%ROWTYPE;    
begin
 exec :record_to_gets := get_unlocked_records;
 dbms_output.put_line(record_to_gets);
end;
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 4, column 7:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "" when expecting one of the following:

   := . ( @ % ;
The symbol ";" was substituted for "" to continue.
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

What is the error that I am doing here ?

Since my ultimate goal is to call the function and get the result in java, how to call this function to get the first record in java ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EXEC**[UTE] is a `SQL*Plus` command and prepending variable with a colon is done in `SQL*Plus`, but in `PL/SQL` **EXECUTE IMMEDIATE** might be used whereas that's not needed in your case, only using such an **assignment** without prepending the local variable is enough :

```
DECLARE
  record_to_gets table_to_test%ROWTYPE;   
BEGIN
  record_to_gets := get_unlocked_records;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(record_to_gets.col1);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(record_to_gets.col2)
END;
/
```